# How to get Instagram token?

Tags: ios, oauth, uiwebview, afnetworking, instagram

I'm trying to get oauth_token in Instagram API. I saw their documentation. So I see the operation of getting token like this: uiwebview loads special request url with client id and redirect uri, when user clicks "Accept" server redirects to my redirect uri with CODE. Then I have to post recieved CODE with client id and client secret. Here is my loginViewController code. I'm trying to POST data with AFNetworking. What am I doing wrong?

I can only get the CODE, but I can't POST it back to get token.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [loginPage loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?
client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://MY_REDIRECT_URI/&response_type=code"]]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:
(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    //here I'm getting the CODE
    NSURL *clickedURL = [request URL];
    NSString *URLString = [clickedURL absoluteString];
    NSArray *tmpArr = [URLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    code = [tmpArr objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"code: %@", code);
```

What to do next??

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented OAuth a few times and suggest you make use of [gtm-oauth](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/). It's fairly easy to integrate and handles all of the possible errors etc when using OAuth. Alternatively AFNetworking has some OAuth projects that are under development. [OAuth1](https://github.com/mattt/AFOAuth1Client) / [OAuth2](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client)

You can build your own but you will need to handle all of the errors returned as well as build a method of navigating back and fourth between pages within the webview which gtm-oauth already does for you.

Comment: Thanks for help, AndyDev! I got it by myself :)

Comment: please share how you got it, i cant get the access token.